# Is there no sense of 'absolute' in the universe?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, potential, differentiation, density

Imagine we are talking about electric potential (e.g. gravitational potential or electric potential or whatever, it doesn't matter), then we have:
\begin{equation}
dV = \textbf{E} \cdot d\textbf{l},
\end{equation}
where $dV$ is the infinitesimal change in the electric potential, $\textbf{E}$ is the electric field and $d\textbf{l}$ is the infinitesimal change in the position of the charge. Then, if we want to know the potential difference, we integrate the equation above (i.e. mathematically, find the difference between $V$ at the final position and $V$ at the initial position). And mathematically, we have $V$ as a function of the position of the charge, although we don't know what the exact function would be as we are interested in the **change** of $V$ only. If we want to find the 'absolute' $V$, we need to define a position where $V = 0$. That is fine.

However, here comes the counterintuitive bit: suppose now I am considering the electric density (e.g. again, mass density or electric density or whatever, it doesn't matter). I am considering a string of charge to simplify my discussion (the string has one dimension only). And we have:
\begin{equation}
dQ = \rho_qdx,
\end{equation}
where $dQ$ is an infinitesimal charge over an infinitesimal section of string, $dx$, and $\rho_q$ is the charge density. Mathematically, this also indicates that $Q$ is a function of $x$. How does this make sense? Now, $Q$, is also relative i.e. like $V$ above, we don't know the absolute value of it unless we define for some $x$, $Q = 0$. Also, to find the charge on the string, mathematically speaking, we just find difference between charge at both ends of the string. How does this physically make sense? Does this have anything to do with field? I.e. in this case, in there a 'charge density field'?

However, in physics (and in real life), we don't really have this concept of 'relative' charge, do we? Is charge a quantity in a relative sense or not?

Comment: I don’t really understand what you’re asking, but charge density depends on the reference frame, while charge itself does not. There are various Lorentz-invariant quantities that you can call “absolute” because all inertial observers agree on their value.

Comment: $Q$ only depends on $x$ only if charge density is non-uniform across string. To find total charge on the string you have to integrate $dQ$ expression along all $x$ interval $[0,L]$ which is a sum of all charge on the string, not a difference of charges at the string ends, you have mis-understood something.

Comment: Your title and your question body are at odds.  The question asks if anything is absolute, but the body asks if a very specific thing, electric charge, is absolute.

Answer (score 1):

It makes perfect sense to say that the total charge $Q$ along a length of string from $x=0$ to $x=l$ is given by

$\displaystyle Q(l) = \int^l_0 \rho_q(x) dx$

And if we want some value of $l$ for which $Q(l) = 0$, we can certainly say that $Q(0) = 0$ (and there may also be other values of $l$ for which this true).

Answer (score 1):

After writing an equation involving $dQ$ and $dx$, you write:

> Mathematically, this also indicates that Q
> is a function of x
> .

No, it indicates that $dQ$ is a function of $dx$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is *a* sense of absolute. The "potential" that has an absolute zero point is the thermal potential, that is the absolute temperature. In an irreversible process the dissipated work $q$ can be written as the sum $$q=\Delta \theta \delta S + \Delta \phi \delta m - \Delta p \delta V +\Delta \mu \delta n + \Delta \psi \delta e +.... \tag{1}.$$
Here the various transported quantities are: entropy $\delta S$, gravitational mass $\delta m$, volume $\delta V$, chemical species $\delta n$, electric charge $\delta e$, etc. These quantities are transported through potential differences: thermal potential (that is empirical temperature) $\Delta \theta$, gravitational potential $\Delta \phi$, pressure $-\Delta p$, chemical potential  $\Delta \mu$, electrostatic potential $\Delta \psi$, resp.

Every one of these potential differences are differences of relative, not absolute, potentials. The product of the potential difference through which the conjugate quantity transported is the amount of reversible work is needed to effect that transport.

In other words, in a reversible process the sum total of all the work is zero, that is $q=0$. When the process is irreversible then it is dissipative as expressed in the inequality $q>0$, specifically the dissipated work can be written as a product $$q=T^*\delta S^* \tag{2}$$ as a product of two *positive* quantities in which $\delta S^*$ is the irreversibly produced entropy at temperature $T^*$ so that the total entropy of the system and its environment increase by $\delta S^*$ amount while $T^*$ represents the absolute temperature with a well-defined zero point so that scale of $T$ is the same as that of the empirical temperature scale in Eq. (1): $\Delta T = \Delta \theta$.